# How can I schedule SQL Server to import files from a directory into a table periodically

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I import spreadsheet into a table automatically?

Usually scheduled, maybe 9am of everyday. I have a program that spits out reports to a designated folder. I need SQL Server to pick up those reports each day or at a schedule timing, read it into a designated table.

I know MS Access has something like a AutoExec function, however I assume SQL Server should have something more sophisticated as I have to manually run MS Access if I was going that route.

Comment: Create an SSIS package to load files into the database and Schedule a SQL Agent job to run that SSIS package everyday at 9am.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some answers to your question.
https://blog.learningtree.com/using-openrowset-to-read-excel-worksheets-from-sql-server-part-2-linked-sql-queries/

At first, i use openrowset option but, that option had issues with the time (the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 stopped working), so i made from scratch a clr procedure with C# to do the job and that worked well for me.